# Sitecore user manager search

Tags: search, sitecore, user-management

I'm trying to search for users in the user manager window and I'm not getting any results. For example "admin" is a existing user but it doesn't return any result. Do you have any ideas?

Note: Role Manager works fine

Cheers

Comment: Do you see a list of users come up when you load the User Manager? Like the ones beginning with "A". Which browser are you using?

Comment: Try replacing the files in your `/sitecore` folder with the ones from the default zip, I've had the same issue but don't know exactly why.

Comment: Hi Shriroop, when I load the User Manager all the users are visible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not working?  I know this might seem like a silly question but with large amounts of users, I've seen the user manager search be quite slow in returning results (and you don't really get a visual cue that it's actually working).

I've also seen this behavior when using "switcher" technology for my userbase.

Am not aware of any fixes unfortunately, sorry.

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm pretty sure that is not returning any result but I'll double check first thing in the morning. The user list is around 200 users so I don't think it is related. I'll post my findings...

Comment: 200 users doesn't seem enough to cause this issue. I've seen it when in the 100s of thousands. Not sure what else the issue could be, but I'll do a bit of digging.

Comment: No luck with that one Mark... Thank you though! I've trying to compare with other sitecore solution and everything seems to be ok but I'll keep trying.